# Streaming issues ..path is null log

Tags: android, path, webcam

Im trying to develop an app that gets stream from JMF streming webcam.. i can stream my webcam by using jmstudio. but i cant watch it on my tablet pc.. here is my code and log ..

```
    String path = "rtsp://192.168.1.211:2000";
    MediaController mc= new MediaController(this);
    vw.setVideoPath(path);
    vw.setMediaController(mc);
    vw.requestFocus();      
    mc.show();
    vw.start();
```

> 09-26 04:17:17.307: D/CLIPBOARD(22762): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(22762): native_setup
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): constructor
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): setListener
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: I/MediaPlayer(22762): path is null
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: D/MediaPlayer(22762): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(22762): setDataSource: path rtsp://192.168.1.211:2000
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): setDataSource(rtsp://192.168.1.211:2000)
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): setVideoSurfaceTexture
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer-JNI(22762): setAudioStreamType: 3
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): MediaPlayer::setAudioStreamType
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): setVideoSurfaceTexture
>
> 09-26 04:17:24.807: V/MediaPlayer(22762): prepareAsync
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: V/MediaPlayer(22762): message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: E/MediaPlayer(22762): error (1, -2147483648)
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: V/MediaPlayer(22762): callback application
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: V/MediaPlayer(22762): back from callback
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: E/MediaPlayer(22762): Error (1,-2147483648)
>
> 09-26 04:17:55.147: D/VideoView(22762): Error: 1,-2147483648

Comment: please correct the formating of the stacktrace

Comment: So what u think ? why i get that error ?

Comment: i don't think the "path is null" is of concern. it is an "info" log, and probably simply means it cannot be treated as a local file. "error (1, -2147483648)" is the real deal, i think

Comment: given the search results on this error, probably a compatibility issue between your android version and the flux encoding

Comment: it 4.0 version on my tablet.. how to correct it ?

Comment: what kind of encoding does your flux use?

Comment: this http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html may help. look at the profile you are using for rtsp, as well as the resolution of your flux